# How to give different border for each series in pie chart using highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

[image]

I am able to get the chart but I'm not able to get the different border for each series.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the borders? You can refer to the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yk5mgbk5/1/?

Comment: I want different border color for each series.

Answer (score 2):

Set a border color for each point individually (slices in a pie are points, not series).

```
{
    name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
    y: 56.33,
    borderColor: 'blue'
  }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/yk5mgbk5/3/

Comment: Is it possible to get the border only for outer portion and with some padding as shown in above image.

Comment: It is not possible with just one series. You would need to create a different line and move outside the inner slices. It can be done with the renderer or ,probably, creation of a dummy second series.